# Create a unique indicator two join two datasets in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I combine four columns in a dataframe in pandas/python to create a unique indicator and do a left join?

Is this even the best way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

```
example: make a unique indicator (col5)
then setup a join with another dataframe using the same logic
col1     col2      col3     col4    col5
apple    pear      mango    tea     applepearmangotea
```

then do a join something like

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='col5')
```

Comment: What _are_ you trying to accomplish? Your question needs more information; what's an example of input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the same whether its 4 columns or 2.  You don't need to create a unique combined key.  You just need to `merge` on multiple columns.

Consider the two dataframes `d1` and `d2`.  They share two columns in common.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 0, 'a', 'b'],
    [0, 1, 'c', 'd'],
    [1, 0, 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 1, 'g', 'h']
], columns=list('ABCD'))

d2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 0, 'a', 'b'],
    [0, 1, 'c', 'd'],
    [1, 0, 'e', 'f'],
    [2, 0, 'g', 'h']
], columns=list('ABEF'))
```

`d1`

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  a  b
1  0  1  c  d
2  1  0  e  f
3  1  1  g  h
```

`d2`

```
   A  B  E  F
0  0  0  a  b
1  0  1  c  d
2  1  0  e  f
3  2  0  g  h
```

We can perform the equivalent of a left join using [**`pd.DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
d1.merge(d2, 'left')

   A  B  C  D    E    F
0  0  0  a  b    a    b
1  0  1  c  d    c    d
2  1  0  e  f    e    f
3  1  1  g  h  NaN  NaN
```

We can be explicit with the columns

```
d1.merge(d2, 'left', on=['A', 'B'])

   A  B  C  D    E    F
0  0  0  a  b    a    b
1  0  1  c  d    c    d
2  1  0  e  f    e    f
3  1  1  g  h  NaN  NaN
```